username with "/" gets truncated
I am trying to SSH to Linux box with username containing /.
For example: tes/t
But the characters after / get truncated and user is seen as tes during SSH. SSH then fails with this user since its invalid.
Even the audit log in the machine shows user as tes.
Note:

I have configured the user as tes/t with valid permissions and the same is seen in database also.
I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Any idea where these session find the truncated version?
sh Log:
sshd[310956]: info Failed password for tes from 10.120.64.33 port 56498 ssh2

audit.log: 
15:09:17.305Z [tes]: Login_Denied - - apparently_via=Remote ip=10.120.64.33 auth=PAM In


did you try by chance tes\/t while running the ssh command ? it's just to protect the / in the name.

what's your exact ssh invocation, i.e. how do you pass the user name?

@admstg, that would not matter, since the shell would just remove the backslash before ssh saw it. You'd have to write something like 'test\/t' to have ssh see the backslash. But then, is there anything that says usernames could be escaped like that in ssh?

also, user names with / are not standards-compliant and I can see multiple ways how they would lead to problems. So, almost certain it'd be sensible for SSH to not even try with user names containing slashes.

Please [edit] your question to show exactly how you're invoking ssh with this user name. Include the ssh command that you're running along with any relevant parts of your .ssh/config file.

i tried running all combinations like ssh 'tes/t'@1.2.3.4 , ssh 'tes/t'@1.2.3.4 from my shell .but dint work due to username restriction in ubuntu as stated below.

You can't log in as a user containing a slash on Ubuntu 22.04; systemd won't let you. This is rather well-documented:

Slashes are not permissible in POSIX user names, so expecting it to work through ssh is a rather daring assumption


3.437 User Name
A string that is used to identify a user; see also User Database. To be portable across systems conforming to POSIX.1-2017, the value is composed of characters from the portable filename character set. The <hyphen-minus> character should not be used as the first character of a portable user name.
3.282 Portable Filename Character Set
The set of characters from which portable filenames are constructed.
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 . _ -
The last three characters are the <period>, <underscore>, and <hyphen-minus> characters, respectively.


systemd explicitly documents that slashes are forbidden.


Rules that systemd enforces
[…]

Similar, no slashes, as these have special meaning in file system paths


So, you plain couldn't log in as test/t.

ssh itself happily sends usernames containing slashes, and sshd receives them in full; I get the impression the username is filtered by PAM. The SSH protocol doesn’t assume POSIX, and SSH can be used to access non-POSIX systems — so it’s not a daring assumption from my point of view. But your answer conclusively explains why it can’t work when accessing a Ubuntu system, even if SSH doesn’t mind.

hmm, so I wonder if it's the PAM libraries or the individual PAM modules involved that have that restriction. And what would happen if one was running sshd without using PAM. (It at least has UsePAM no, not that I've ever tried.) And what then happens if systemd is presented a username like that.

@StephenKitt ah, true. but that throws me back to the question I posted in the question comments: how did OP specify the user?

I know some serial console servers where one can encode the port number in the username when logging in with ssh, i.e. username:port13. So indeed it's good that ssh isn't excessively strict about that :)

hmm I tried ssh me/foo@somesystem, and the logs on the remote show sshd[225157]: Connection closed by authenticating user me 2001:..., i.e. it looks like sshd already stripped the slash? And logging in with me:foo... well, logs me in. (remote is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

@ilkkachu in my experiments with sshd -d, I see “debug1: userauth-request for user tes/t service ssh-connection method none” so the username gets as far as that, and becomes tes after that (“Invalid user tes from …”). But I haven’t found where the filtering happens.

@StephenKitt, auth2.c uses the colon as separator for "style", whatever that is, and the source deb from Ubuntu has debian/patches/selinux-role.patch, which adds similar code for the slash, apparently for some SELinux -related thing. https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/auth2.c#L287 . Oh, right, the colon is mentioned under the AuthenticationMethods config option

@ilkkachu ah, for the role! Nice, thanks for finding that.

oh that's why ssh and logging utility were truncating the username in their display.
Thanks a lot everyone for the help.
